# Git push credentials should be the information in GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

When I run `git push origin master` I am asked to supply credentials. For example:

**Username: stackover
/ pass: stack0v3r**

And the push is successful.

When I go to my GitLab account. I actually see the name **AnotherUser** made a commit that I set before pushing using those commands:

```
> git config --global user.name "AnotherUser" git config --global

> git config --global user.email "anotheruser@example.com"
```

The thing is, this PC will be used by many other people and I don't want them to **manually** change this settings. 
Is there a method which takes the credentials and automatically use them as informations for GitLab?

Ideally this is how it would work: another push, any other user(and the console is configured to AnotherUser). When the any other user will enter user/pass AnyOtherUser, the information on GitLab will show that this was pushed/commit by AnyOtherUser.

I hope I was clear.
Many thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, you want each users (unix users) to push on gitlab with different identity?

Comment: Please specify if you're using HTTPS or SSH auth

Comment: Hello @Arount. Mostly YES. For example when is YOUR turn to use this PC, you will push to GitLab, it will ask for you credentials and the push will be successful. But when I will go to GitLab project, I will see that user "AnotherUser" made a commit, NOT YOU! I don't want that every time you(Arount) use this PC to manually apply those config user commands.

Comment: Hello @ibt23sec5 . HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using git+ssh authentication, you have at first to put your public SSH key in your Gitlab account. You don't know how to do it, [here](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/03/04/add-ssh-key-screencast/) is a little tutorial.

Otherwise if you're using HTTPS auth, create and get a [personal access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) from your personal settings in Gitlab. This token you'll put in the repo url with your username:

```
git remote set-url origin https://username:your_new_acces_token@gitlab-url/namespace/project.git
```

Comment: I know about SSH Key and about HTTPS, but this still doesn't solve my problem. You still put the user to enter a command. The default user now set on git config global username is TEST. When I will push, on GitLab I will still see TEST user made a commit, and not the username I provided for example on your remote set-url command

Answer (score 0):

So you want to handle several Gitlab identities.

The basic setup would be to create one UNIX user by identity:

- `/home/firstuser/.gitconfig`:

  ```
  [user]
      email = firstuser@foo.bar
      name = 'First User'
  ```
- `/home/seconduser/.gitconfig`:

  ```
  [user]
      email = seconduser@foo.bar
      name = 'Second User'
  ```

*etc...*

So, each user will use his own `~/.gitconfig` and you Gitlab will display `First User` or `Second User` in function of that.

Comment: Hmm, this still is done manually. Lets try this another way, GitLab shows what user made a commit(AnotherUser), but can you actually see what HTTPS Credentials he used?(I just need the username he used to push). GitLab username can be different from https login username. On GitLab you can see AnotherUser, but for login he used anotheruser123